# AngularJS ng-options not binding to ng-model

Tags: angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-options

There are similar questions here, but I still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have ng-options populating a  tag in a form. In the form's submit controller when I console.log the ng-model it comes back undefined. I'd appreciate any help.

```
<label ng-controller="educationController">
    select your level of education
    <select ng-model="selectedEducation" ng-options="education for education in degrees" required>
    </select>
  </label>
```

this is the controller

```
angular.module('drsApp.reviewerApplication');
app.controller('educationController', educationController)
function educationController($scope){
$scope.degrees=[
  "Bachelor Degree",
  "Master Degree",
  "Doctorate Degree"
  ]
};
```

this is in the form's controller

```
console.log("education: "+ $scope.selectedEducation);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's showing undefined because you write the ng-model name wrong.The ng-model name should be "selectedEducation" instead of "education" like in console--

> console.log("education: "+ $scope.selectedEducation);

you can check it here--

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="educationController">

        select your level of education
        <select ng-model="selectedEducation" ng-options="education for education in degrees" required>
        </select>
        <button ng-click="formSubmit()">Submit</button>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('educationController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.degrees=[
              "Bachelor Degree",
              "Master Degree",
              "Doctorate Degree"
         ];
            $scope.formSubmit=function (){
              console.log("education: "+ $scope.selectedEducation);
            }
        });
  
    </script>

    

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i'm not completely sure why, but i can't define my controller like that. 
" var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('educationController', function ($scope)" and even when i corrected the console.log, it's still undefined. i actually caught that error after submitting the question.

Comment: @Jen then copy your code of that part and edit your question, without seeing your code it can not be understand where is the problem

Comment: thank you for your help. i updated the form controller. i have to declare the education controller just as i did, or the page breaks

Comment: @Jen that's great.If my answer is helpful for you then accept my answer.

Comment: i'm sorry, you must have misunderstood. it's still not working. i made the updates to the original question. it still doesn't work, but if i use plain javascript i can make it work.

Comment: @Jen did not clear what's your problem ? if you explain your problem with more details it will help to understand

Comment: you declared "app.controller" but i do not see defining what is "app" is.did you declared it in the other portion of  code ? As your code in the question ,did you forgot to declare var app=angular.module('drsApp.reviewerApplication');

Comment: yes, the "app" is declared earlier in the program. the drop down box is set by the ng-option. when i select an option, the ng-model is not updated.